# Create combinations of arrays with values from two arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have `two arrays with ids` that have **linked lengths**. By **linked lengths** I mean that if `ArrayA` has `length = 4` then `ArrayB` will have the `length` equal with `(ArrayA.length * (ArrayA.length - 1)) / 2` (which means if `ArrayA` has `length = 4` then `ArrayB length = 6`, if `ArrayA` has `length = 5` then `ArrayB length = 10` and so on).

So let's say these are my arrays: `ArrayA = [1, 2, 3, 4]` and `ArrayB = [a, b, c, d, e, f]`.

I have to create a `new array of arrays` based on the next logic:

[image]

In the end the new array should look as it follows, where the second parameter is a value from the first array and the third parameter is a value from the second array:

```
[
  [uuidv4(), 1, a],
  [uuidv4(), 2, a],
  [uuidv4(), 1, b],
  [uuidv4(), 3, b],
  [uuidv4(), 1, c],
  [uuidv4(), 4, c],
  [uuidv4(), 2, d],
  [uuidv4(), 3, d],
  [uuidv4(), 2, e],
  [uuidv4(), 4, e],
  [uuidv4(), 3, f],
  [uuidv4(), 4, f]
]
```

In the end, I should return this kind of array no matter the size of the arrays, but the arrays have some kind of linked length.

I can't do this with a simple mapping because I don't know how to achieve this kind of logic.

The base idea is that `ArrayA` is an array of team ids and `ArrayB` is an array of match ids and I need to add two teams id for every match id.

Thank you for your time! If something is unclear, I'll try to explain better.

Comment: why (1,a) (2,a) but not (1,e) ? why (2,e) (4,e) but not (3,e) ? without knowing this, it's impossible to code it

Comment: The base idea is that the first array is an array of team ids and the second array is an array of match ids so i need to add two teams per match. It doesn't matter the order (1a, 2a, 1b, 3b; it also can be 1c, 2c, 1a, 3a) but i guess it's easier to get them in order. @malarres

Comment: @malarres it seems the logic starts from the letters. This means that we should loop the largest array and each of them will have 2 items from the shortest array. Like "a" has 1,2, "b" has 1,3 (incremented a 2nd index until it reaches the end) and so on

Comment: Yes @BrankVictoria atm I am trying to achieve this using for loops because with mapping i guess is pretty hardcore

Comment: Essentially similar to round-robin or league-games in some of the larger sports tournaments. Each team plays every other team at least once - probably a points tally decides which ones advance to the next level. Fair understanding?

Comment: can you also provide the final array if ArrayA will have 8 teams, because I can't get the logic for match `e` or `f`. I mean, if we'll have 8 teams, then they should have 4 matches each, or what? Thanks

Comment: It is my understanding that: If there are 8 teams, there will be a total of 8 * 7 / 2 = 28 matches. And each team will play 7 matches. Will await OP to clarify.

Comment: yes @jsN00b, this is the answer. For every item in the larger array (the match ids array) there should be two other arrays (one for a team and the other for the other team). Also for your upper question, is it right, i create a match for every two team for let's say a tournament, and then for the winners i will do the same, but with smaller arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have seen in your image the logic is for each element in the largest array, assign 2 elements from the shortest one without duplication. In order to achieve this the idea is to loop the largest array and assign in a new array the elements of the shortest array using 2 different index (xIndex0, xIndex1).

In the example below you can see how xIndex0 is pointing to the first element to add from the shortest array, and xIndex1 is pointing to the second element to add, we are incrementing those index depending if we have already reached the end of the shortest array.

```js
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var xIndex0 = 0
var xIndex1 = xIndex0 + 1
var y = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
var result = [];
y.forEach((elem,index) => {
    result.push([null, x[xIndex0], elem]); //replace null with everything you need
    result.push([null, x[xIndex1], elem]);
    
    xIndex1++;
    if(xIndex1 > x.length-1)
    {
    xIndex0++;
    xIndex1 = xIndex0 + 1
    }
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes! I was close to your answer when i decided to remove the normal `map`. My problems were that I was incremented the `xIndex1` after the `if body` and in if i was checking for `xIndex0 + 1 === x.length`. Thank you so much. Smart!